# PHP object properties are null after instantiation

Tags: php, web-applications, session-variables

Here is what is making my brain hurt. First, I know just enough php to explain it in about 5 minutes. I am however fairly versed in object oriented programming. The situation:

I am trying to build a php application to be used as an intranet only tool. My thought is to save the current user in the session. I created a PHP model of my database user table. In the code I am authenticating the user and if the user authenticates then I am creating a User object and saving it in the session. The problem is that the User object is created but all of the properties are null. I have researched on here and php net for some answers and have tried several things but the problem persists. I do not think it is php related, I absolutely think it is something I am doing wrong but just can't put a finger on it. Here is the relevant code sample from the login script. To get here the password must validate, the variable `$users` is the direct return from the function in my database controller. Since the variable is included in the `var_dump` the code returning that variable may not be needed. I have tried passing the relevant array elements separately to the constructor, I have tried passing the full array, I have used `serialize` and `unserialize`. I have tried to set them using `$this->property = $someValue` .

```
if ($hash) {
    $current_user = new User($users);
    $_SESSION['current_user'] = serialize($current_user); 
    $current_user = unserialize($_SESSION['current_user']);
    var_dump(session_id());
    var_dump($users);
    var_dump($current_user);
    var_dump($_SESSION['current_user']);
}
```

Here is my constructor:

```
class User {
public $userid;
public $fname;
public $lname;
public $email;
public $username;
public $function;
public $d_joined;
public $is_internal;
public $is_active;

function __costruct() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    if (!empty($arguments)) {
        foreach ($arguments[0] as $key => $property) {
            if ($property_exists($this, $key)) {
                $this -> {$key} = $property;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I have tried `_construct($args)` and `_construct(array($args))` and nothing. Here is the output of the `var_dump()` calls

```
string 'cgotecrpu7soqvepoimjo2s116' (length=26)

array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=20)
  'userid' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'fname' => string 'First Name' (length=4)
  1 => string 'First Name' (length=4)
  'lname' => string 'Last Name' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Last Name' (length=8)
  'email' => string 'email address' (length=21)
  3 => string 'email address' (length=21)
  'username' => string 'username' (length=9)
  4 => string 'username' (length=9)
  'password' => string 'hashed password:salt' (length=65)
  5 => string 'hashed password:salt' (length=65)
  'function' => string '4' (length=1)
  6 => string '4' (length=1)
  'd_joined' => string '2013-01-14' (length=10)
  7 => string '2013-01-14' (length=10)
  'is_internal' => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => string '1' (length=1)
  'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  9 => string '1' (length=1)

object(User)[2]
public 'userid' => null
public 'fname' => null
public 'lname' => null
public 'email' => null
public 'username' => null
public 'function' => null
public 'd_joined' => null
public 'is_internal' => null
public 'is_active' => null

string 'O:4:"User":9{
s:6:"userid";N;
s:5:"fname";N;
s:5:"lname";N;
s:5:"email";N;
s:8:"username";N;
s:8:"function";N;
s:8:"d_joined";N;
s:11:"is_internal";N;
s:9:"is_active";N;}' (length=162)
```

So from what I can see, the initial array `$users` has the correct data. The `User` object is created in the variable `$current_user` . However, when I try to access an object property I get an error about accessing an object property from a non-object. It looks like the session variable is not an object, but the `$current_user` is, even though it has null properties. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Note the function is `__construct()`, not `__costruct()` or `_construct`... And don't serialize objects in your session unless you prefer for some reason to call `session_start()` before your class definitions are loaded without an autoload. It will be serialized on save in a session already, no need to do it twice.

Comment: Not looked through all your code, but have you tried looking at the value of `$_SESSION['current_user']` or `$current_user` before you serialize/unserialize?

Comment: Your constructor is designed to parse multiple variable passed to the object instanciation while your are passing a single (array ?) value to your class. I think there is something  wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor looks wrong for the thing you want to do, I think you should do it this way :

```
 /**
 * Constructor set each public values with the ones passed from the passed array
 * @param array $userDatas Array containing the user datas
 */
function __construct($userDatas) {
    foreach($userDatas as $key => $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. First I was scared that misspelling construct was the problem, but it was spelled correctly in my code, the "n" must have been a casualty of my rushed attempt to get it formatted and posted and get out of the office while the gettin' was good.